# Limit of logarithmic derivative of power series of non-negative Coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

Take a power series $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$, with the restriction that $0\leq a_k\leq C^k$ for all $k$, such that the power series has a radius of convergence $R=\frac{1}{C}$. Assume that both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are uniformly convergent, so that it may be differentiated term-by-term. I'd like to investigate the limits $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kx^{k-1}}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k},$$ and $$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{C}^-}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{C}^-}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_kx^{k-1}}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k}.$$

I found the first limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{a_1}{a_0}$ to be rather straightforward. But I'm not too sure about the second, since they both diverge at the boundary (geometric series). From a couple of plots, it seems that if the series is indeed infinite (i.e. there does not exist $K$ such that $a_k= 0$ for $k>K$), $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ diverges to infinity. However, I'm not too sure how to prove this. I had an idea to use L'Hopital's Rule, but I don't think I can apply it for an infinite polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ may well converge at $x=R[=1/C]$. This is the case for, say, $f(x)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n^3$ or for a more elementary example \begin{align}f(x)&=1+2x^2-(1-x)^2\log(1-x)\\&=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n^2-1)}.\end{align}

On the other hand, we have $$\lim_{x\to R^-}f(x)=\infty\implies\lim_{x\to R^-}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\infty$$ since otherwise (assuming $f(0)>0$) $$\int_0^R\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx=\log f(R^-)-\log f(0)$$ would be finite.